# sqlite query in oncreate decimal and other value types

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

as i am making an app that has to connect to an database on a server in the future i want to make now a database on my android phone that has the same columns and column names.

in my oncreate i made following

```
                 public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + databasetabel + "(" +
                recordnummer + " BLOB NOT NULL, " +
                bezoekrapportnummer + " PRIMARY KEY BLOB AUTO INCREMENT, " +
                bezoekrapportdatum + " DATETIME NOT NULL, " +
                herstellingsoort + " VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL, " +
                totaleduur + " VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL, " +
                servicenummer + " BLOB NOT NULL, " +
                ONBEKEND + " VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL, " +
                klantnaam + " VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, " +
                adres + " VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, " +
                machinenummer + " BLOB NOT NULL, " +
                omschrijving + " TEXT NULL, " +
                duur + " VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL, " +
                postcode + " VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL, " +
                gemeente + " VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, " +
                merk + " VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, " +
                model + " VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, " +
                serienummer + " VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, " +
                opmerkingen + " TEXT NULL, " +
                werkgereed + " VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL, " +
                extratijd + " VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL, " +
                urenstand + " BLOB NOT NULL, " +
                gecontroleerdbureel + " VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL, " +
                onderhoudsfiche + " VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, " +
                uitsplitsen + " VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL, " +
                opmerkingbureel + " TEXT NULL, " +
                ONBEKEND2 + " BLOB NOT NULL, " +
                orderverwerkdatum + " DATETIME NOT NULL, " +
                ordernummer + " BLOB NOT NULL, " +
                basisservicenummer + " BLOB NOT NULL, " +
                verzonden + " VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL );" 
                );
```

except for the BLOB statements i have everything declared as in my database on my server
(BLOB were all of the type DECIMAL(5,0) or simular)

anyway, BLOB or DECIMAL or ...
all of it is giving following line in my logcat:

```
   08-24 11:59:04.578: E/SQLiteLog(5918): (1) near "BLOB": syntax error
```

except for this line there are no more red log lines

as this is the first time i have to work with sqlite i think my query is wrong
how to fix it so i have a table that allows me to put in the same data as on my server

i found out already on the net that DECIMAL doesn't exists in sqlite
that is why i changed them to BLOB
with no effect

thanks in advance

Comment: What is the actual SQL command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<column_name> PRIMARY KEY BLOB AUTO INCREMENT` is not valid (see [create table](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html)):

- sqlite syntax is 'AUTOINCREMENT'
- constraint should appear after datatype
- auto increment is only allowed for integer primary keys

try to replace this column with :

`<column_name> INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT`